# How to change previous and next 7 days using bar charts mvc c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, charts

I am going to create one charts module in m project.and i am also getting success for the create chart module. i am right now create **bar charts**.using charts.min.js. and i am show data last 7 days date wise.but now i want to change my logic and we need to change previous and next days in to 7 days. i have add to button for the pre and next in the charts. but now how can do that click on button i have not idea.

This is my query in sql server =>

```
SELECT CAST(dateadd(day, T.i, getdate()) AS Date) AS DateColumn, uf.TotalCount
        FROM (VALUES (-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)
        OUTER APPLY
        (
           SELECT COUNT(UF.InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
           FROM Users UF               
           WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,UF.InsertDateTime, DATEADD(DAY, T.i, GETDATE())) = 0 and UF.IsLogin = 1
        ) uf
```

This is my cshtml page =>

```
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                <div id="btn" class="hidden" style="margin-left: 200px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <a href="#" class="previous round" onclick="GetPreviousWeek()">&#8249;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="next round" onclick="GetNextWeek()">&#8250;</a>
                </div>
```

This is my Js code for the load charts. =>

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    LoadCharts();
});

    function LoadCharts()
    {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetChartsData',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
             var arrlableForSignUpUser = new Array();
            var arrdataForSignUpUser = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                arrlableForSignUpUser.push(data.data[i].DateColumn);
                arrdataForSignUpUser.push(data.data[i].TotalCount);
            }
            CountSignUpUser(arrlableForSignUpUser, arrdataForSignUpUser);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
  }

 function CountSignUpUser(arrlableForSignUpUser, arrdataForSignUpUser) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: arrlableForSignUpUser,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Successfull Sign-Ups',
                data: arrdataForSignUpUser,
                //backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,1)"
                backgroundColor: '#34999c'
            }]
        },
    });
}
```

here this is my charts see like this =>

[image]

in this charts i have add 2 button now i want to click on this button want change days in to periods of 7 days. so any one please give me some hint how can do that.

Comment: If you want to select by week you may try to use the week number in the select but if you always want to start at `today minus n*7 days` you need a variable for n and pass it into the select, replacing  `= 0` with `= n*7`. the buttones then increment/decrement n and trigger the loadChart..

Comment: @TaW yes i have done like this. thanks for the replay.